# tf-idf - accessing a large sparse scipy matrix & getting the highest values

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, tf-idf

For the tfidf result matrix, I wanted to get the top tfidf values. I saw how one could set max features amount for the tfidf vectorizer, but that is for the words with the top tf count. I want to still get the high values for the tfidf, which could include words with low tf. One idea I looked up is doing something like `tf_idf_matrix.sum(axis=0)`, which would sum up the columns. This works in my code, but because of 113k columns, print wont show them all. If I could use something like `argsort()` to access the top K column sum values, that would be helpful.

This question stems off my original question which [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920808/dealing-with-a-large-amount-of-unique-words-for-text-processing-tf-idf-etc).

The reason is that I want to know which words are the ones I should look at closer, and not necessarily the ones that have the highest frequency.  I would also like to know about the "anomalies" that is, words that might not appear in all or many documents/posts but could have a high tfidf in a one or fewer documents.  In case there are other approaches I should consider, I wanted to explain this.

Thanks

Comment: To get the `k` highest column sums: `col_sum = tf_idf_matrix.sum(axis=0).A.squeeze(); idx = np.argsort(col_sum)[-k:][::-1]` and now `idx` holds the column numbers of the top 5 column sums, and you can get the values from `col_sum[idx]`.